# What is the fastest way to create HTML table with data from JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, javascript-framework, jqote

I have the following code to convert my JSON dataset to html table.
I want to know if it is the fastest method, or should I use jqote2 with jquery to write template?

### Requirements:

- can change col definitions with a click (client can change how to view table, col definition array will change, and table can be rebuilt)
- sorting, filter & pagination (I believe raw data can be sorted and table can be rebuilt)
- conversions (If say 1 col contains data of length in different units, than a new col in raw data set can be added having data in 1 same unit so that data can be sorted)

So can somebody guide me if I am on right track or am I working on something that already exists?

```
<div id="hii"><!-- table loads here --></div>

<script>
var set1={ // JSON dataset & col definitions
    'col':[ // definition/template of data to load in column cells
        [function(x){return '<a href="?sid='+x[1]+'">'+x[0]+'</a>';}],
        [function(x){return '<a href="?id='+x[2]+'">'+x[2]+'</a>';}],
    ],
    'data':[ // raw data, output table has only 2cells/row using these 3 values from each row
        ['Name 1','00000001','Value 1'],
        ['Name 2','00000002','Value 2'],
        ['Name 3','00000003','Value 3'],
        ['Name 4','00000004','Value 4'],
        ['Name 1','00000001','Value 5'],
        ['Name 5','00000005','Value 1'],
        ['Name 6','00000006','Value 1'],
        ['Name 7','00000007','Value 2'],
        ['Name 8','00000008','Value 6'],
        ['Name 9','00000009','Value 3'],
        ['Name A','00000010','Value 7'],
        ['Name B','00000011','Value 7'],
        ['Name C','00000012','Value 1'],
    ],
};
function tbody(x){ // function to create table, using dataset name passed to x
    for(i=0,data='';i<x.data.length;i++){
        data+='<tr>';
        for(j=0;j<x.col.length;j++){
            data+='<td>'+x.col[j][0](x.data[i])+'</td>';
        }
        data+='</tr>';
    }
    return data;
}
document.getElementById('hii').innerHTML='<table>'+tbody(set1)+'</table>';
</script>
```

Comment: also, is method to create table optimal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net/examples/). It works with jQuery and is also themable. There are quite a few options you can set that can meet your requirements, and even more.

Comment: I guess, http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html is closest to my requirements. I have gone through it earlier, but just now seen that they offer fnRender for columns where I can format data whatever way I wish.

Comment: yes, fnRender is the option you need to format your column data :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not so easy to do. Take a look at Sencha (extJS), especially Grids - http://www.sencha.com/learn/legacy/Tutorials, http://www.sencha.com/learn/legacy/Tutorials#Grids

Comment: Thanks for the information, though I find Datatables.net more easy to start with.

Answer (score 1):

jquery/jqote can do this too:

```
$('#container tbody').empty().html($('#row_template').jqote(set1));

<script type="text/x-jqote-template" id="row_template">
<![CDATA[
    <tr id="<%=this.id%>_valuebox">
        <td><%=this.name%></td>
        <td><%=this.value%></td>
    </tr>
]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the jQuery Templates Plugin.

http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/

```
<ul id="movieList"></ul>

<script id="movieTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <li><b>${Name}</b> (${ReleaseYear})</li>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var movies = [
        { Name: "The Red Violin", ReleaseYear: "1998" },
        { Name: "Eyes Wide Shut", ReleaseYear: "1999" },
        { Name: "The Inheritance", ReleaseYear: "1976" }
    ];

    // Render the template with the movies data and insert
    // the rendered HTML under the "movieList" element
    $( "#movieTemplate" ).tmpl( movies )
        .appendTo( "#movieList" );
</script>
```

Comment: I have gone through it, but as per the following link, it is slower than jqote2 http://www.viget.com/extend/benchmarking-javascript-templating-libraries/