# how to use javascript or jquery create table fast

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a table by click a button,and i need to save the table to the database .this is the code to create table but i think this is so long,how can i create it fast?

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
        var table1 = document.createElement("table");
        var table2 =document.createElement("table");
        var thead = document.createElement("thead");
        var th1 = document.createElement("th");
        var th2 = document.createElement("th");
        var th3 = document.createElement("th");
        th1.innerHTML="Count";
        th2.innerHTML="Date";
        th3.innerHTML="Price";
        document.body.appendChild(div);
        div.appendChild(table1);
        div.appendChild(table2);
        table2.appendChild(thead);
        thead.appendChild(th1);
        thead.appendChild(th2);
        thead.appendChild(th3);
```

Comment: That's about as fast as you're going to get. jQuery would make the code shorter, but certainly no faster. Why do you believe this is slow?

Comment: i mean this code is too long , is there any ideas to shorter them and create table easily?

Comment: Use a templating system, such as http://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the fastest way to create HTML table with data from JavaScript array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887253/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-create-html-table-with-data-from-javascript-array)

Comment: You're doin it right. Additionally create a documentFragment which contains your table and than append it to the div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code is too long then I recommend creating an html table structure inside a div that is not displayed. Then when the user clicks the button then you could

1. Display the table that is hidden.
2. Clone the table and append it to something (if you expect to create the table multiple times)

Your code would then look like so (cloning wise):

jQuery:

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function(){
  $(document.body).append($('original').clone());
});
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function(){
    document.body.appendChild(document.getElementById('original').cloneNode());
}
```

And here is the html table you can have hidden.

```
<div style="display: none;">
    <table id="original">
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td> 
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td> 
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This reduces greatly your javascript code.

Comment: yes i know clone , but i need create tables and save the content to the database

Comment: @user5065694 so you clone and you update the table to your needs and then you send it. no?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make some enhancement than you can use precompiled template like muchtache.js :

```
<table>
   <tr>
   <th> Count </th>
   <th> Date </th>
   <th> Price </th>
</tr>
{{#jsonObject}}
<tr>
   <td>{{Count1}}</td>
   <td>{{Date1}}</td>
   <td>{{Price1}}</td>
</tr>
{{/jsonObject}}
</table>
```

in javascript, you can write your javascript `jsonobject` as :

```
jsonobject : [{
    count1 : 1,
    date1 : 12/12/2012,
    price1 : 100
},
{
    count1 : 2,
    date1 : 12/12/2013,
    price1 : 200
}
]
```

for full muchtache example visit [Json Object into Mustache.js Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24923871/json-object-into-mustache-js-table)

Answer (score 0):

The following function might help:

```
function html2dom (html) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = html;
    return div.removeChild(div.firstChild);
}
```

Here is how to use it:

```
document.body.appendChild(html2dom(''
+ '<div>'
+     '<table></table>'
+     '<table>'
+         '<thead>'
+             '<th>Count</th>'
+             '<th>Date</th>'
+             '<th>Price</th>'
+         '</thead>'
+     '</table>'
+ '</div>'
));
```

Live demo:

```js
document.body.appendChild(html2dom(''
+ '<div>'
+   '<p>Paragraph.</p>'
+   '<ul>'
+     '<li>Item 1.</li>'
+     '<li>Item 2.</li>'
+     '<li>Item 3.</li>'
+   '</ul>'
+ '</div>'
));

function html2dom (html) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = html;
  return div.removeChild(div.firstChild);
}
```